# Can you use an if statement to decide what UserForm to put information in?

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement, userform

I have the following issue: I have UserForm A and UserForm B in excel. Both UserForms call UserForm C. The user chooses an ID number from UserForm C that I then want to be put into a label in either UserForm A or UserForm B depending on which one is currently open.

I have searched for a possible answer or alternative solution to this but haven't been able to find anything that helped. I am trying to avoid having to make two UserForm C's if I can help it. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Edit: Right now my code for Userform C is initiated by a click event. So, the user selects the ID number from a list box which gets saved automatically into a label that is hidden. When the user clicks the save button the hidden labels caption (the ID) gets transferred to UserForm A. What I would ultimately like is for there to be some kind of if statement to differentiate if Userform A is open and if not then the hidden labels caption would instead get transferred to UserForm B. I have thought about using an option button for the user for choose from, but not all users have access to UserForm B so I would prefer to not let the user try to determine where they should be saving the ID to.

The code I have for the click event is:
    Private Sub cmd_save_Click()
    UserFormC.Label1.Caption=UserFormA.Label1.Caption
    Unload UserFormC
    End Sub

Comment: Could you show us some code?  We might be able to help you get it working.

Comment: I added the code that I currently have but it doesn't account for the possibility of a different UserForm being opened. Is there a was of saying If UserForm A called UserForm C to open then transfer the information back to UserForm A? I have only been working with VBA for a few months so I only know the basics.

Answer (score 0):

You could base it on option button values.  On your FormC place two option buttons with the text FormA and the other FormB.  Then in the click or change event of the control you are "choosing an ID number from UserForm C", use an if statement

```
If OptionButton1.Value = True Then
    UserFormA.Label1.Value = "A"
Else
    UserFormB.Label1.Value = "B"
End If
```

That is all I can offer without seeing your forms and or code.